# Laravel 5 how to use memcache

Tags: php, laravel, memcached

I have installed memcache on my linux server. when  i try to use it from core php file or codeigniter framework it is working.

```
        $memcache = new Memcache;
        $memcache->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
        $memcache->set('a', 'test');
        echo $memcache->get('a');
```

Same code is not working in laravel controller. I tried using

```
use Cache \Cache and use \Memcached  (at the top )
```

i also tried memcached but it is still working. i am getting following error

```
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Memcached' not found
```

Help please..

Comment: updated my question. please have a look

Comment: `use Memcached` not `use \Memcached`

Comment: did u update  .env file for cache driver?

Comment: `CACHE_DRIVER=memcached` in .env?

Comment: yes sir. it is updated with memcached as a driver

Comment: (1/1) FatalThrowableError
Class 'Memcached' not found

in MemcachedConnector.php line 69

Comment: memcache != memcached

Comment: please guide me how to use memcache here in laravel

Comment: not memcache ... `memcacheD` ... the laravel docs have the prerequisites for the drivers

Comment: which extension you want to use memcached or memcache.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for help guys.
I install memcached on my server. 
Update .env file to CACHE_DRIVER=memcached
In controller file i added `use Memcached;`
and use below code and it worked

```
    $memcache = new Memcached;
    $memcache ->addServer('localhost', 11211);
    $memcache->set('a', 'tet');
    echo $memcache->get('a');
    exit;
```

Thanks